# BAT script to automate importing VBA modules (.BAS) into Excel file and running macro

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, vbscript

I've been trying to search for similar questions but wasn't able to find much for precisely what I'm looking for. I could have missed it in my search - if any of you can find a previous thread for this, please link it for me :)

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to fully automate an Excel report, which involves running a macro that I have a .BAS file for. I've seen tutorials for how to create a .VBS and .BAT script to automate the running of macros, but I wan't to also automate the importing of the macros. For example:
- I have my base dataset that I want to run the macro on, which comes in a standard Excel file (xlsx), which I save in a consistent location
- I have my .BAS file which contains the macro I want to use every time, saved in a different location from my reports
- What I am seeking: to have a .BAT file on my desktop that will automate: 1) Opening my standard xlsx file, 2) Saving it as an xlsm, 3) Importing my .BAS file with my macro, 4) Executing the macro, and 5) Closing Excel.

The key part I am missing is how to have the .BAT script automatically import the .BAS module into my Excel file. If I have to manually open Excel and import the module, I might as well just manually run the macro as well, thus eliminating the purpose of trying to create a .BAT file to automate :)

If anyone can provide guidance, that would be much appreciated. I hope my post was clear - if any questions, I can clarify in comments.

Comment: You normally store vba modules in Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: @Mark - Unless you have snippets that you store somewhere else. I've got one to get the last used row that I use a bunch.